# Passing substring value of gridview to textbox

Tags: c#-2.0

Please suggest me any idea to pass sub string value of grid view in text box.

frm.txtcustcode.text = dg.cells["custcode"].value.ToString().Trim();

I need to pass (0000001234) "01234" to txtcustcode.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code might work fine:

```
frm.txtcustcode.Text= dg.Cells["CustomerCode"].Value.ToString().Trim().Substring(5,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly.
The code :

```
dg.cells["custcode"].value.ToString().Trim();
```

is a value in a grid and the value you get  by using the code is : `0000001234`
You would like to display this value in a textbox on the form as a value : `01234`

If this is the case you could do the following:

```
    //If the value of custcode always starts with 0's but wont contain 0's in the number.
    String sCustCode = "0000001234";

    sCustCode = sCustCode.Replace("0", "");
    sCustCode = "0" + sCustCode;

    MessageBox.Show(sCustCode); //Displays 01234

    //Or if your CustCode can contain a 0 and always starts with 0's.

    sCustCode = "0000001234";
    int num = Int32.Parse(sCustCode);  //Depending on the number format use the correct cast.
    sCustCode = "0" + num.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(sCustCode); //Displays 01234

    //Or you dont want to use a Cast to get your code in the fear of dataloss for some reason.
    sCustCode = "0000001234";

    int index = 0;
    int position = 0;
    foreach(char myChar in sCustCode)
    {
        if (myChar != '0')
        {
            position = index;
            break;
        }
        index++;

    }

    if (position == 0)
    {
        //No starting 0 found
    }
    else
    {
        sCustCode = sCustCode.Substring(position - 1, sCustCode.Length - position +1);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(sCustCode); //Displays 01234
```

I am sure there are better ways of doing this, it depends on the purpose.
Hope this can help you in the correct direction.